# Swift "is" operator with type stored in variable

Tags: swift, types

This piece of code works as expected. "integer is int" is printed in output.

```
let integer = Int()

if integer is Int {
    println("integer is int")
}
else {
    println("integer is not int")
}
```

I want to use `is` operator in the same way as I can use `isKindOfClass` method - with class (or rather type) stored in variable. It would look like this:

```
let integer = Int()
let intType : Any = Int.self

if integer is intType {
    println("Integer is int")
}
else {
    println("Integer is not int")
}
```

Unfortunately this produce an error: `Use of undeclared type 'IntType'`.

`IntType` in `if` condition has even a different color (if you paste it to playground) than in other places in source code, suggesting that (as the error message says) its being treated as a class name (like `IntType` would be a class). But it isn't. It means that `is` operator cannot be used with variables on the right side?

I want to use `is` operator because it can compare not only classes, but also other types.

How can I check if value has type which I expect?

---

I found dirty solution, but it's really far from being reliable...

```
let integer = Int()
let intType : Any = Int.self

func ==(left: Any, right: Any) -> Bool {
    let leftString = "\(left)"
    let rightString = "\(right)"
    return leftString == rightString
}

if (integer.dynamicType as Any) == intType {
    println("true")
}
else {
    println("false")
}
```

Works perfect, but be careful - cause this one is also true:

```
if (integer.dynamicType as Any) == ("Swift.Int" as Any) {
    println("true")
}
else {
    println("false")
}
```

Is there a better way?

---

Ok, I'll explain further what do I want to achieve. I have object which manages instances of generic class instances. At some point I need to pick one of those generic class instances basing on type of generic. Example:

```
class GenericClass<T> {}

struct ToolInfo {
    let tool : AnyObject
    let jobType : Any
}

class Manager {
    var tools = Array<ToolInfo>()

    func pickToolForTheJob(job : Any) -> AnyObject {
        return tools.magicMethodWhichReturnProperTool()
    }
}

let viewTool = GenericClass<UIView>()
let rectangleTool = GenericClass<CGRect>()

let manager = Manager()
manager.tools.append(ToolInfo(tool: viewTool, jobType: UIView.self))
manager.tools.append(ToolInfo(tool: rectangleTool, jobType: CGRect.self))

manager.pickToolForTheJob(UIView()) // i want to get viewTool here
manager.pickToolForTheJob(CGRect()) // i want to get rectangleTool here
```

Currently i have `ToolInfo` struct, because as far as I know its not possible to get type passed in `<>` while instantiating generic class object. But I'm still unable to compare it.

Comment: also thought about implementing === operator, but it doesn't solve it elegantly. another thought to wrap it within a `struct` as optionals do, but don't know if it's acceptable for you.

Comment: Not sure why do you need to store class into a variable but I think typealias are made for these things

Comment: Guys I've updated question to show my problem, maybe some of you will suggest other way to solve this problem.

@rshev how would it look like? Could you please explain it further (with a struct) or show some pseudo code example?

Comment: @zellb how would it look like with typealias?

Comment: `typealias intType = Int`

Comment: I used this : `if type(of: instance) == Class.self {...}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It means that is operator cannot be used with variables on the right side?

Correct. The right side of `is` must be hard-coded at compile-time.

If you don't need polymorphism and your types are class types, you can use `===` to compare the `dynamicType` of an instance with a class type. That's the only way you're going to get a type-in-a-variable on the right side of something in pure Swift.

Comment: You said "your types are class types". This means that It's impossible to check compare type of non class type? If you could update your answer with this info to make it clearly visible I would accept this answer as closing this question.

Comment: "This means that It's impossible to check compare type of non class type?" You can compare them with `is`. But not if what's on the right side is some sort of type-in-a-variable. As I said in my answer, the right side of `is` must be hard-coded. This is because Swift is strict about typing; it needs to know the type of everything _at compile time_.

Comment: I don’t know what “this” is.

Answer (score -2):

Here is my experiment with `enum` type container (sorry, written `struct` by mistake in the comment earlier):

```
enum TypeContainer {
    case SomeInt(Int)
    case SomeString(String)
    case SomeBool(Bool)

    init(int: Int) {
        self = .SomeInt(int)
    }

    init(string: String) {
        self = .SomeString(string)
    }

    init(bool: Bool) {
        self = .SomeBool(bool)
    }
}

let a = TypeContainer(string: "123")
let b = TypeContainer(int: 88)
let c = TypeContainer(bool: true)

switch a {
case .SomeInt(let i):
    println(i)
case .SomeString(let s):
    println(s)
case .SomeBool(let b):
    println(b)
default:
    break
}
```

You can do something like this in your project.